# Reading strings from a text file in C and determining end of line

Tags: c, string, scanf, printf

I am trying to read words and numbers from a space and tab delimited text file.  I need to identify lines which contain "Step" and "False".  I also need to store each word or number separately so that some can be thrown out later.

I am having trouble trying to write the part of the code which identifies "False" at the end of a line.  I need the code to recognize that it has reached False and break the for loop.

Note:  It is designed so that you input your own path.  This portion works.  Also, I have read that fscanf is much harder to use than fgets and fputs, but the data files i am reading are very consistent in format.  This seems to work well for my purposes, as some entries will need to be doubles.

```
    int j;
    int k;
    char i[4];                       
    char File_path[40];
    char dummy;
    char stuff[7] = "False"

    printf("Input Path: ");
    scanf("%s", &File_path);
    printf("Reading:  %s\n\n",File_path);
    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen(File_path, "r");
    for(j=0; j<7 && i != stuff; j++)
    {
        fscanf(fp,"%s",i);
        fprintf(stdout,"Read:  %s\n",i);
    }
    fclose(fp);
```

The file I am reading is:

```
True.0 kinda false False False
```

This returns:

```
Reading:  c:\\Data\\1.txt

Read:  True.0
Read:  kinda
Read:  false
Read:  False
Read:  False
Read:  False
Read:  False
```

I have tried changing stuff to "False" and I get the same result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't compare strings that way in C.  You need to use `strcmp()` or `strncmp()` to do that:

```
for (j = 0; j < 7 && strcmp(i, stuff); j++)
```

That loop conditional will break the first time `i` points to `"False"`.  You also need to make `i` larger - you're going to overflow that buffer on the first read in your example.

Editorial - you really do probably want to use `fgets()` and `strtok()` or one of its relatives to work through this stuff.

Comment: As far as the buffer, I assumed that the buffer was being automatically expanded. I made it too small on purpose for that reason. I had seen a few functions where they would automatically expand as needed. because it managed to copy even though it wasnt allocated the correct length, I assumed it was copying correctly. I guess this is not the case, but it doesnt explain why the strings still copied correctly.  I first learned with MATLAB, so my knowledge of memory allocation is poor.  And I just saw the function atof.  That should allow me to use gets.  Thanks!

Comment: Automatic expansion of buffers *never* happens in C, as far as I know.  Maybe there are some crazy libraries that work otherwise, but even those can't change the size of an array.